# Can't run Spring Boot test application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Trying to complete Spring Boot tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#initial

Here are my classes:

```
package hello;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {

            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
                System.out.println(beanName);
            }

        };
    }

}

package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

and pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I am trying to run it with this command: "mvn package && java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar", I am getting this:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe"
>
> -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\Антон\IdeaProjects\SpringBootTest
>
> "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2018.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3"
>
> "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2018.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf"
>
> "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2018.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=63804:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.3\bin"
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2018.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher
>
> -Didea.version=2018.2.3 package && java
>
> -jar target/spring-boot-test-0.1.0.jar
>
> **Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -jar**

I tried to execute it from windows console and from "Maven Projects" -> "Execute Maven Goal".

Can't  find anything about this error.

Comment: Have you tried "mvn spring-boot:run" (from the root of your project, where your pom resides)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open command prompt and goto your where pom.xml presents 
run **`mvn clean install`**
once you get the message build successful

goto target folder by cd target
then run the command `java -jar <file-name>.jar`

or goto project folder folder and directly run :

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

if you are still getting the error message while running then some spring config is wrong.

create new spring boot application from `https://start.spring.io/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made it from https://start.spring.io/, but I still have the same problem. 

But, now I am able to simply run it with Shift + F10, and the output the same as it should be from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You may can try to run `mv spring-boot:run`, from the root folder of your project.

Or, run `mvn clean install`, clean is not a goal for default, so is good add clean goal to clean target folder.